# how to use for loop inside a echo statement in bash shell script and output to file

Tags: bash

I have found something similar on here but not exactly what I am looking for.
I am essentially trying to automate the creation of an `nginx` file which may have multiple domains attached to it.

**My input looks like this:**

```bash
./setup.sh domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com domain5.com
```

**What I am trying to do:**

1. Prepend `www.` to each of the input domain names (on the same line)
2. Output all of it to a file.

Currently this breaks:

```bash
   SERVER_HOSTNAME=${1}
   shift
   SERVER_DOMAINS=(${@})

   echo '
   server {
           listen 80;
           listen [::]:80;

           root /var/www/${1}/html;
           index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

           server_name ${@} '
           for i in "${@}"; do echo "www.${i}"; done
           echo '
           more lines here.
           more
           more
           more

   ' > output.text
```

Currently this loop kind of works except it puts the `www.$@` on separate lines and only outputs the 2nd part of the echo statement to the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered breaking it down into multiple `echo`s, one for the header, one for the inside content, and one for the footer? That's more efficient than what a lot of the answers are telling you to do (creating a subshell during heredoc invocation); those answers will _work_, but they do so at a performance penalty.

Comment: Note that you can make a redirection apply to a compound command: `{ echo "first"; for item in "$@"; do echo "second $item"; done; echo "$last"; } >output.text` -- so the need to use `>` doesn't force you to make it all one `echo`.

Comment: please update the question to show a) the (wrong) output generated by your code and b) the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a heredoc and a bash parameter expansion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

(( $# > 0 )) || exit 1

cat <<EOF
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/$1/html;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ${@/#/www.};

    more lines here.
    more
    more
    more
}
EOF
```

So that:

```bash
./setup.sh domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com domain5.com
```

Would output:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.domain1.com www.domain2.com www.domain3.com www.domain4.com www.domain5.com;

    more lines here.
    more
    more
    more
}
```

Comment: Wow, Nice! I ended up using Printf instead which more or less solved my issue but yours is much more elegant. Thank you!

Comment: how would you save this output to a file?

Comment: you can redirect the output in the first line `cat <<EOF > output.text`